# configure: error: Please reinstall the BZip2 distribution

Tags: php, macos, bzip2, libzip

I am trying to compile php from source on mac with the bzip2 extension and I keep getting an error saying

> **checking for BZip2 in default path... not found**

I've tried setting the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS but that doesn't seem to work.

The dylib is in */usr/local/opt/bzip2/lib* and the header files are in *usr/local/opt/bzip2/include.*

Answer (score 6):

Install dependencies for php

```
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libonig-dev libreadline-dev libtidy-dev libxslt-dev libzip-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue. I resolved it by installing `bzip2` by using `brew`.

`brew install bzip2`

Answer (score 4):

This also works:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```